# The drop-down shows but when I click it nothing happens can some one tell me why?.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code and for some reason the drop-down shows but when I click it nothing happens can some one please help me.

ps. Iam using Brackets, jquery, and bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">

<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/unifrakturmaguntia:n4:all.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="Javascript.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [It actually works](https://jsfiddle.net/z5gg0v4g/)

Comment: Works for me too, in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE 9 :) It’s likely due to some other error on your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.  You might have an error in your `Javascript.js` that is stopping scripts from running.  You might also have a conflict as you are importing both the Bootstrap CSS and Javascript twice; once from a CDN, and once from a local source.